# Samsung Galaxy S6/7/8 - RuntimeException / throwIfCannotDraw

Tags: android, imageview

recently as android 7.0.0 poped up and devices came with it my app started throwing exception with no particular reason. The problem is I have no idea what might be the problem - what I know is that it only occur on Samsung devices with Nougat and its about drawing some ImageViews. Can libs like Admob or Universal-Image-Loader do this or ?

anyway here's the full exception - hope some1 can help me out ...

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
  at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1420)
  at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:545)
  at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1286)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18313)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17291)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18075)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17286)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18075)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18316)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17291)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18075)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17286)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18075)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17286)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18075)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18316)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:850)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17291)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:666)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:672)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:780)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3103)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2899)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2493)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1493)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7040)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:638)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: Did u able to solve this issue. Or know reason for it?

Comment: not yet, I cant get my hands on a galaxy device ...

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: This is not related to the Samsung, but I've seen it happening more often there, the other phones are Nokia and Sony devices with OS 8/9

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check whether the bitmap is recycled before its get drawn?

Comment: well, the problem is it does not give any debug infos, it just crashes ... I need at least an idea of what could it be in 7.0.0 and up that causes this - funny thing it only happens on samsung devices.

Comment: @wexeteme Running into same issue. Only on Galaxy devices and crashlytics doesn't give me enough info to determine what image it is about an haven't been able to recreate issue. Did you solve it? And could you post your sollution :)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when using a large bitmap as background of a TextView.
Simply reducing the size of the bitmap in the main Drawable folder solved this issue for me.
I guess that it could be even more elegantly solved by placing bitmaps of different resolutions in multiple Drawable folders